# Css adjustment for aligning elements of my page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know what I did, but I either shifted my header and nav to the right or the rest of the page to the left. Using tw bootstrap. I can't figure it out. I've fire-bugged it and looked through my css edits and don't see any negative margins (is what I suspect).

http://skeeterz71.com/auto

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it. What should be showing is the header logo and top nav and the rest of the page should line up on the left and top nav right with the right side of the page.

Thanks
T

Comment: Hi I'm having trouble figuring out what it is that you want (the layout)

Comment: If you look at the logo and nav bar (full screen) you will see that it is indented some compared to where the left edge of the automobile picture is just below it.. I need the logo, nav bar and the left edge of the automobile photo to all line up together. I hope I was able to clarify this some. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you want to achieve, but from what I'm guessing, adding these CSS changes might help:

```
.span12 {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.span6 {
width: auto;
}

#social-wrapper {
float: right;
}

ul.nav.pull-left {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
}

.topNavRow {
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: -11.5%;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
     .topNavRow {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: -8.5%;
     }
}
```

(You can just add that styling to your Main.css) - if that helps :)

Comment: Hi,It almost worked. My logo is off the left edge and the social button got pulled in from the right edge.. Span 6 I believe. But, I think those were actually in the right spot originally. It is everything below that appears to be pulled to the left. If you notice the page is not centered in the browser, where the header and nav bar were before I added thise edits.

Comment: My Bad, I forgot to upload the changes

Comment: oh, oke but then I would advise just putting a Class on the row that contains the logo and social buttons and giving it the following margins: margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: -11.5%;

and then just add a media tag for 1200px to again adjust the right-side margin

OH! and you might want to add ul.nav.pull-left {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
}